# Task Scheduler Cannot Find Specified File

Tags: cmd, scheduled-tasks, windows-8.1

I want my PC to create a folder with the day's date everyday. I cannot get it to work with Task Scheduler. Here's what I have:

- Program/script: `mkdir`
- Add arguments: `TEST_%date:~10,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%`
- Start in: `D:\File Backups\`

Whenever I run this from command prompt, it works. I don't understand why it isn't working with Task Scheduler. It says `The system cannot fine the file specified. (0x80070002)`.

When I run it from command prompt, here's what I say:

```
mkdir "D:\File Backups\TEST_%date:~10,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%"
```

I am using Windows 8.1.

Comment: If D: is a network drive it won't work. Use UNC `\\server\share\folder\file.ext`.

Comment: Do you run the scheduled task under a certain user context or under system context? If you are trying to specify `mkdir` directly, you won't succeed as this is an internal command of `cmd` (command prompt), so try with `cmd /C mkdir ...` or `"%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe" /C mkdir ...` instead.

Comment: The format of date string of environment variable `DATE` depends on Windows Region and Language settings defined for the __used user account__. This could mean that the date string is formatted different on running the `mkdir` as scheduled task using system account than when you with your user account run the same command. For a Windows Region and language independent solution see [How to get current datetime on Windows command line, in a suitable format for using in a filename?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/)

Comment: I am trying to solve similar question. is this solved?

Comment: @aschipfl :  I tried using 


"%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe"  /c mkdir  "Z:\some_name_commercial\%CurrentDate%" with no success.


P.S :  Z:\ is the network drive (NAS mounted)